Bigquery: Table not found after running a DML
The issue I've been facing is related to the sudden vanishing of tables after creating them or after running a DML command. For example:

I create a  table in my project called project.dataset.tbl_1.  It is successfully created, and i can see its schema, details, etc. Then I run a INSERT statement into it, or a DELETE, or UPDATE, and the first time it runs the full statement, it recognizes the table and executes the DML command, but a few seconds after running the command, the table vanishes from the project, and it cannot be queried. I can recreate the table, and it will exist as long as I don't run a DML command to modify it. So, if I have a procedure that inserts and then updates the data (considering same schema for both tables), like:

BEGIN

Insert into `project.dataset.tbl_1`
select * from `project.dataset_1.tbl_1`;

Update `project.dataset.tbl_1` set <whatever variable> WHERE <whatever condition>;

END;

The output will be something like:
INSERT successful.
UPDATE failed: Reason:  table project.dataset.tbl_1not found.

All of a a sudden,  batch routines started to fail. When looking at the logs, the reason was Table not found. This is odd, because none of the tables had expiration dates, and all of them were created at the same specific location, which is EU.

I have been struggling to understand why something like this would happen, considering that the tables are created in the same location (EU), with no expiration date.
Has anybody faced something like this?
I recreated the tables and ran the DML commands but the problem persisted.
